# How to check element have or not have before declare var using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to check element have or not have before declare var using javascript ?

on bottom code, not have `checkbox id="w"` but how to check elements before declare var ?

if have `checkbox id="w"` , We will declare `var w_val = document.getElementById("w").checked`

But not have `checkbox id="w"`, not to declare `var w_val = document.getElementById("w").checked`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function test()
{

var w_val = document.getElementById("w").checked
var x_val = document.getElementById("x").checked
var y_val = document.getElementById("y").checked
var z_val = document.getElementById("z").checked

alert(w_val);
alert(x_val);
alert(y_val);
alert(z_val);

}
</script>

<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="x" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="y" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="z" value="3"/>
<button onclick="test()">OK</button>
</form>
```

Comment: if(typeof variablename 'undefined') ????

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why do you wish to check if a javascript variable has been declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns `null` when a match doesn't exist. Also, `null` is falsy, so you can use it as a condition for `if`.

```
var w = document.getElementById('w');
if(w){
  // element with ID w exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have included jQuery on your page, you can always write something like this:

> if ($('#w').length !== 0) {
>       // your code here if element found.
>     }

Answer (score 0):

```
function isChecked(id){
    return document.getElementById(id).checked;
}

var w_val = document.getElementById("w") ? isChecked("w") : undefined;
var x_val = document.getElementById("x") ? isChecked("x") : undefined;
var y_val = document.getElementById("y") ? isChecked("y") : undefined;
var z_val = document.getElementById("z") ? isChecked("z") : undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check it with an if condition, like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('yourElement').length > 0){ ... }
```

Comment: `getElementById` does not return something that has a length, it returns an element.